# Passing a HttpPostedFileBase type using $.Post or $.Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this action in my controller.

```
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        //code for uploading goes here.
        return View();
    }
```

Is there a way on accessing this action using $.post or $.Ajax?
in my ***view*** i have these code.

```
<input type="file" name="fileData" id="fileData" multiple/>
<button>Upload</button>
```

first i'm trying to use this code

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
   $.post('@Url.Action' + $(".filedata").val(),function(data){
      console.log(data);
   });
});
```

but when i try to break point on my "**upload**" action, the "**filedata**" variable has a ***null*** value.

I don't know what's the problem. Hope you can help me guys.

Comment: You can't upload a file this way with Ajax. You have to use an `<iframe/>`or other asycn upload methods like http://www.plupload.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: So, what's the best way to do?

Comment: ah, on **swfupload**, is it related on uploadify? i tried uploadify and everything works fine. I can access my action using that one. But the problem is on my sessions. The value of my session variable got empty or null, that's why i removed my uploadify.

Comment: Yeah that's an annoying flash bug. you have to manually add these values to the uploadify postback. There may also be problems with authorization cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a IFRAME that  'll be use to make the post with the file.

Like this:

```
<iframe id="targetUpload" name="targetUpload"></iframe>
```

In the form you set the target to the iframe.

```
<form target="targetUpload" name="file" runat="server" method="post" id="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")">
```

And a submit button

```
<input type="Submit" value="Upload">
```